# Critique request for my monologue: 我下课以后常常去我的实习。 我以后我的实习我有课一遍。……

Tags: grammar, writing-critique

Is anyone willing to help me edit this monologue for grammatical errors? If so, I would really appreciate it. I have chosen the most simple words I know to make performing it easier.

> 我下课以后常常去我的实习。 我以后我的实习我有课一遍。 我的最后课六时完毕某些天， 八时其他天。 然后我常常开始我的回家作业。
> 至少有一次每个星期我有Amnesty International会议. 这是一个人权组我跟我的男朋友开始。
> 如果我有会议，我得回家作业我开始后。 我的奖学金需求五个课，所以我有课每天。 周末，我也很多了学习。
> 如果我有时间，我星期五试试玩儿跟我的朋友们，和星期日吃饭跟我的妈妈。 有时我恐怕没有时候。 如实, 我很忙和不能等到休息。 但是，
> 我有这些机会是很祝福。

> After class I often go to my internship. After my internship I have class again. My final classes end at 6pm on somedays, and 8pm on other days. After, I often start my homework. Every week at least once a week I have Amnesty International meetings. This is a human rights organization that I started with my boyfriend. After I have a meeting, I start my homework. My scholarship requires me to take five classes, so I have class every day. On the weekends, I study a lot. If I have time, I try to go out with my friends on fridays and eat dinner with my mom on sunday. Usually I don't have time. Honestly, I am extremely busy and I can't wait till break. Yet, I am very blessed to have these opportunities.

Comment: Can you pinpoint specific problems or uncertainties you have? This is rather lengthy, and we don't just provide bulk proofreading/translation services.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help.

### Correction

我下课以后常常去实习 （ i often go to intern-ship whenever the class is finish ).
实习以后我还有一堂课（After the inter-ship i still have a lesson).
我的最后一堂课有时会在六点钟结束，而其它天都会在八点钟结束。 (My last lesson will ended at 6 o'Clock sometimes,while others day will ended at 8 o'Clock) .
然后我就会开始做作业。（Then i will start to do my homework) .
每周至少有一天我都会有个Amnesty International会议. （At least one day a week i will have a meeting of Amnesty International.
 
这组/会议是由我和我男朋友举办/开始，它是关于人权。(This group/meeting is organized/started by me and my boyfriend, It's about human rights.
如果我有会议，我得回家作业我开始后。// im not sure what you're trying to express here ,perhaps you can translate it to English first and then i will help you to translate it back to Chinese/ 
奖学金的条件是必须拥有五个科目，所以我几乎每天都有课。(The requirements of scholarships is must have five subjects, therefore i almost have classes everyday. 
周末，我也必须学习。 (Weekend, i have to learn also) 
如果我有空闲的时间，我会尝试在星期五和朋友一起出去游玩及在星期日与妈妈一起共餐. (If i have free time, i will try to go out and play with friends on Friday, and having meals with mother on Sunday.
有时我担心我没时间。 (Sometimes I worry that I do not have time).
如实, 我很忙和不能等到休息。 // im not sure what you're trying to express here 
但是, 我觉得这些机会是很庆幸的 。 （However, I feel that these opportunities are very fortunate)

Comment: 通过这路，中文给Amnesty International是“国际特赦组织”。

Answer (score 2):

我下课以后常常去实习。 实习结束之后继续上课。 我的最后一节课有时下午六点结束，有时晚上八点结束。然后开始我的家庭作业。 每个星期我有至少有一次Amnesty International会议. 这是我跟我的男朋友建立(establish or join?)的一个人权组织。 如果有会议，会议结束后才开始家庭作业。 我的奖学金需要五门课，所以我每天有课。 周末，我也学习很多。 如果我有时间，星期五跟我的朋友们玩，星期天陪我的妈妈吃饭，但是经常没有时间。 的确, 我很忙，几乎没有休息。但是不管怎么说，我有这些机会还是心怀感激的。

Comment: I'd use 创建 instead of 建立 in 这是我跟我的男朋友建立的一个人权组织

Comment: 会议结束后才开始家庭作业 -> 会议结束后才开始*做*家庭作业; 我的奖学金需要五门课 -> 我的奖学金需要我上五门课. To make it reads more smoothly, 星期五跟我的朋友们玩 -> 星期五会跟朋友们玩, 星期天陪我的妈妈吃饭 -> 星期天会陪妈妈吃饭

Comment: If you mean starting an Amnesty International club at your school to similar, I would use "社团."

Answer (score 0):

我下课以后常常**去我的实习**（去实
习）。 “here，我的 can be leave out”

我以后我的实习我有课一遍。 do you mean 我实习后都有课 l have lessons after pratice

我的最后**课六时**（六课时）完毕某些天， 八时其他天。

然后我常常开始我的回家作业。（然后我常常回家做作业）

至少有一次每个星期我有Amnesty International会议.（我至少每个星期有Amnesty International会议。）

这是一个人权组我跟我的男朋友开始。（这是一个我跟我的男朋友参加的人权组织）

如果我有会议，**我得回家作业我开始后**。 我得回家后开始做作业

我的奖学金**需求**（要求）五个课（课时），所以**我有课每天**（我每天有课）。

周末，**我也很多了学习**（学习了很多）。

如果我有时间，**我星期五试试玩儿跟我的朋友们，和星期日吃饭跟我的妈妈。** 我会星期我跟我的朋友们玩，星期日跟妈妈吃饭

**有时我恐怕没有时候。** 有时我恐怕没时间

如实, 我很忙和不能**等到**（得到 ）休息。 cannot wait for having a rest
i cannot have a rest  ➡️ 得不到休息

但是， 我有这些机会是很祝福。我有这些机会很开心。